# Is there any way to see difference between last two versions of a file using hg commands?

Tags: mercurial

I want something like this

hg vdiff filename.txt -lastRevision -secondLastRevision

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know what vdiff is, but how about:

```
hg diff -r rev1 -r rev2 filename.txt
```

Edit: to get the last 2 revisions, that would be:

```
hg diff -r -2 -r -1 filename.txt
```

Type `hg help revisions` for information about specifying revisions.

Comment: I know about this command but I wanna compare last two revisions ...getting last two versions value dynamically...makes sense ?

Comment: Generally, you want them in the opposite order (-r -2 -r -1). That will give you "what changes were made between these two commits" (the reverse gives "what changes would I need to undo the changes between these two revisions")

Answer (score 9):

As of this writing, the top answers refer to `-1`, `-2` and `-3`. The negative integers are historical artifacts and should not be used with modern Mercurial workflows.

Typically, the "last version" means "the currently checked out revision". In that case, to see the changes to `file` in the currently checked out commit, you can use

```
hg diff --change . filename.txt
```

If you'd like to see the last time `filename.txt` was *changed*, you can use

```
hg log --follow --patch --limit 1 filename.txt
```

The `--follow` argument causes `hg log` to follow history, so it'll only output the current revision or its ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
hg diff -r -3 -r -2 file
```

Comment: When Nitesh said "last two versions", I assumed he meant the current version and the one before.